# Regression with lasagne: error

Tags: python, theano, deep-learning

I am trying to run a regression with lasagne/nolearn. I am having trouble finding documentation how to do that (new to deep learning in general).

Starting off with a simple network (one hidden layer)

```
from lasagne import layers

from lasagne.nonlinearities import softmax
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet    

print(np.shape(X)) # (137, 43)
print(np.shape(y)) # (137,)

layers_s = [('input', layers.InputLayer),
           ('dense0', layers.DenseLayer),
           ('output', layers.DenseLayer)]

net_s = NeuralNet(layers=layers_s,

                 input_shape=(None, num_features),
                 dense0_num_units=43,
                 output_num_units=1,
                 output_nonlinearity=None,

                 regression=True,

                 update=nesterov_momentum,
                 update_learning_rate=0.001,
                 update_momentum=0.9,

                 eval_size=0.2,
                 verbose=1,
                 max_epochs=100)

net_s.fit(X, y)
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-23c15ceec104> in <module>()
----> 1 net_s.fit(X, y)

/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nolearn/lasagne.py in fit(self, X, y)
    148             out, self.loss, self.update,
    149             self.X_tensor_type,
--> 150             self.y_tensor_type,
    151             )
    152         self.train_iter_, self.eval_iter_, self.predict_iter_ = iter_funcs

/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/nolearn/lasagne.py in _create_iter_funcs(self, output_layer, loss_func, update, input_type, output_type)
    298         all_params = get_all_params(output_layer)
    299         update_params = self._get_params_for('update')
--> 300         updates = update(loss_train, all_params, **update_params)
    301 
    302         train_iter = theano.function(

/home/alex/src/lasagne/lasagne/updates.py in nesterov_momentum(loss, all_params, learning_rate, momentum)
     38 # such that the gradient can be evaluated at the current parameters.
     39 def nesterov_momentum(loss, all_params, learning_rate, momentum=0.9):
---> 40     all_grads = theano.grad(loss, all_params)
     41     updates = []
     42 

/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/theano/gradient.py in grad(cost, wrt, consider_constant, disconnected_inputs, add_names, known_grads, return_disconnected)
    431 
    432     if cost is not None and cost.ndim != 0:
--> 433         raise TypeError("cost must be a scalar.")
    434 
    435     if isinstance(wrt, set):

TypeError: cost must be a scalar.
```

Thanks!..

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution for this problem yet? I am stuck with the exact same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're using versions of nolearn and Lasagne that are **known to work together**.

Say you've been following the [Using convolutional neural nets to detect facial keypoints tutorial](http://danielnouri.org/notes/2014/12/17/using-convolutional-neural-nets-to-detect-facial-keypoints-tutorial/).  Then the right thing to do is to install the dependencies from [this requirements.txt file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnouri/kfkd-tutorial/master/requirements.txt), like so:

```
pip uninstall Lasagne
pip uninstall nolearn
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnouri/kfkd-tutorial/master/requirements.txt
```

If, however, you're using nolearn from Git master, then make sure you install the Lasagne version that's in the [requirements.txt file found there](https://github.com/dnouri/nolearn/blob/master/requirements.txt):

```
pip uninstall Lasagne
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dnouri/nolearn/master/requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what version of nolearn and lasagne you are using. I did notice that you have `y` as being of shape `(137,)`. From my usage this needs to be `(137, 1)` to work for your case, and, in general, dim 2 needs to match the `output_num_units`.

Try `y.reshape((-1, 1))`.

If this doesn't work it may be a Python 3 compatibility issue.

Comment: I got a similar issue and this solved the problem. Thank you!

Comment: If you're having trouble figuring out what shape your data should have when you send it into NeuralNet: For classification tasks, the target vector `y` must have one dimension only.  For regression tasks, it always has two dimensions, regardless of the number of regression targets.

Here's a bit of code to illustrate this: https://gist.github.com/dnouri/fe855653e9757e1ce8c4